# convert items in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, int, tuples

I have a dictionary set up like so {'USA': ('123456', '456020832'), ... }

The keys are countries obviously, and the other 2 are Area (miles) and population. I need help trying to convert the area and population into int. (they are strings now).

this is what i have:

```
def _demo_fileopenbox():        
msg  = "Pick A File!"
msg2 = "Select a country to learn more about!"
title = "Open files"
default="*.py"
f = fileopenbox(msg,title,default=default)
writeln("You chose to open file: %s" % f)    
countries = {}   
with open(f,'r') as handle:
    reader = csv.reader(handle, delimiter = '\t')  
    for row in reader:
        countries[row[0]] = (row[1].replace(',', ''), row[2].replace(',', '')) 
        #i have tried countries[row[0]] = int((row[1].replace(',', '')), int(row[2].replace(',', '')) ) with no luck 
    reply = choicebox(msg=msg2, choices= list(countries.keys()) )
    writeln(reply + "-\tArea: " + (countries[reply])[0] + "\tPopulation: " + (countries[reply])[1] )
```

thanks! I just keep getting errors about converting so i was looking for some help

Answer (score 1):

When reading change your code to be:

```
countries[row[0]] = int(row[1].replace(',', '')), int(row[2].replace(',', ''))
```

Or, alternatively, an example of how you'd do it afterwards:

```
d = {'USA': ('123456', '456020832'), 'UK': ('12345', '9876544')}
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    d[k] = tuple(int(el) for el in v)
# {'UK': (12345, 9876544), 'USA': (123456, 456020832)}
```

**debugging your `ValueError`:**

Modify your code to be like the following:

```
for row in reader:
    try:
        countries[row[0]] = int(row[1].replace(',', '')), int(row[2].replace(',', ''))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(row)
```

This will catch the `TypeError` and print to the console the rows that it's failing on. You can then look at those and determine why your columns don't successfully convert to an `int`.

Comment: the first option you gave is what i tried and kept getting errors, but for the second one do i have to import anything to use iteritems? i just tried the second method and got the error "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'"

Comment: @erp You're using Python3.x then ? You need to use `.items()` instead

Comment: @erp Also, I think you'll find my first option is syntactically different from yours (you have mismatching parentheses), and will work

Comment: Yes sorry i fixed that right after i posted the comment. Now does this "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)" when talking about  "[k] = tuple(int(el) for el in v) " mean that i need to do the converting 2 times?

Comment: @erp Have you given up on the first example now then?

Comment: Yeah :\ it was giving me this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' --- which is the same one i was getting earlier before i posted. couldnt figure out that error either and no one on here told me why

Comment: @erp I've added a little bit on how to debug your code as to why `int` conversions aren't working - try following that, and hopefully it'll point out why your data fails conversion - It's going to be that one of the columns is blank.... But this way you can see which ones, and how many